# Log the time in between user - a simple timer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple timer.

The user presses a 'start' button. When the user presses another button, I would like to log the time in between.

Could this be achieved with setTimeout?

Comment: the `Date` object is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: try [this jquery fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2dvM/)

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout` shouldn't be used for your situation. The following is a method to display the amount of seconds between clicking "startBtn" and then clicking "endBtn":

```
var date1 = new Date();
document.getElementById("startBtn").onclick = function(){
   date1 = new Date();
}
document.getElementById("endBtn").onclick = function(){       
    var date2 = new Date();
    var dif = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
    var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
    alert(Seconds_Between_Dates);
}
```

You can build from here to get your desired functionality (for example, if the user clicks "endBtn" before clicking "startBtn", the results are inaccurate, of course. You can fix by disabling buttons as needed, etc.)
(thanks to [How Many Seconds Between Two Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates))

Comment: Yeah, I know that you were faster. It didn't stop me from posting my approach anyway ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's really not necessary to use a Timeout for this. All you want to do is measuring two difference between two time dates.

HTML:

```
<span class="startTimer">
    Start Timer
</span>

<span class="stopTimer">
    Stop Timer
</span>

<span class="result">
</span>
```

JS, and no, the use of JQuery is not needed here but I like the way it handles events:

```
(function($){
    var Timer = {
        startTimeInMs: null,
        endTimeInMs: null,
        start: function(){
            this.startTimeInMs = new Date();
        },
        stop: function(){
            this.endTimeInMs = new Date();
        },
        getTime: function(){
            return this.endTimeInMs - this.startTimeInMs;
        },
        bind: function() {
            var self = this;

            $('.startTimer').on('click', function(){
                self.start();
            });

            $('.stopTimer').on('click', function(){
                self.stop();
                self.printResult();
            });
        },
        printResult: function() {
            $(".result").html(this.getTime())
        },
        init: function(){
            this.bind();
        }
    }

    var timer = Object.create(Timer);
    timer.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Date.now()` method, there's no need to instantiate a new Date object each time.

Here's a jsFiddle that measures lap times as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpFnp/

*HTML*

```
<button id="start">start/reset</button>
<button id="stop">lap</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
var startTime = Date.now();

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
    startTime = Date.now();
});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<p>" + elapsedTime  + "</p>";
});
```