# I count the time the user takes to solve my quiz using Javascript but I want the same time displayed on another page

Tags: javascript

How can I  display the same time on another page without using cookies because its just a local website and database isn't such a good idea? Is there something else I can do?

Comment: You want it in real time or at the end ?

Comment: **real time going on**

Answer (score 1):

**local storage** should be very ok.
[image: http://www.alsacreations.com/xmedia/doc/full/web-storage.jpg]

example :

```
    //page A
var counted_time=[your algorithm result];
    localStorage.setItem("mytime_hey", counted_time);

    //page B
        var mytime = localStorage.mytime_hey; 
    $("#mydiv").html("your time is"+mytime+" !");
```

//// if your question is : how to count ? that s another matter. make a difference between 2 date : [How Many Seconds Between Two Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates)

Comment: I don't need it as a particular time actually the time is being counted and then I want to show the user that how much time it took him to complete my questions in another link

Comment: allright. my code does. setItem("whatyouwant", what_var_u_want); ... see my edit