# how to find hh:mm:dd difference between two strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, date

In my app I have two date strings:

Say that they are:
date1 = "2014-03-14 18:25:15";
date2 = "2014-03-14 16:26:15";

I get these date strings based on two events that the customer selects. Now I need to show the difference between these two strings in HH:MM:DD format.

What I am currently doing is, `posting to PHP using AJAX` and then doing the calcuation in the server:

```
$rDate = new DateTime($date1);
$tDate = new DateTime($date2);
$interval = date_diff($rDate,$tDate);
echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Then in the AJAX response handler I print it to a div

My problem is that server trip is just too much an overkill for this. How can I achieve the same thing from browser itself? (Javascript/Jquery/MomentJS)...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe take a look at this posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is a very well featured date handling library for Javascript.

Here's the relevant manual link for Moment.js for what you're wanting to do: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Hope that helps.