# Difference in time between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, flipclock

I am trying to make a countdown clock until the inauguration on January 20, 2017 at approximately 12:00pm using [flipclock.js](http://flipclockjs.com)

How do I calculate the difference (in seconds) between the current time and that date/time?

I currently have:

```
var inauguration = new Date("January 20, 2017 12:00:00");
var now = Date.now();
var diff = inauguration - now;
var clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: "DailyCounter"
});
```

Got it working:

```
    var inauguration = new Date(2017, 00, 20, 12, 0, 0, 0);
    var now = Date.now();
    var diff = inauguration.getTime() - now;
    diff = diff / 1000;
    var clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(diff, {
        countdown: true,
        clockFace: "DailyCounter"
    });
```

Comment: @Dalorzo Well, no. This is something different.

Comment: Haha yeah, although I think it is a bit different than what @Dalorzo linked. We got it working with the answer below. Teamwork makes the dream work `:D`

Comment: When creating a date, don't parse a string, pass arguments directly to the Date constructor: `new Date(2017,0,20,12)`. It's less to type and less problematic given that built–in parsing is mostly implementation dependent. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `inauguration` is a `Date` object. You can get the number of seconds by `.getTime()` function. You need to change:

```
var diff = inauguration.getTime() - now;
//---------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your working code should be:

```
var inauguration = new Date(2017, 00, 20, 12, 0, 0, 0);
var now = Date.now();
var diff = inauguration.getTime() - now;
diff = diff / 1000;
var clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: "DailyCounter"
});
```

The idea of `getTime()` was part of the solution, and along with a couple of other minor changes the above code is now working.

Also, the original implementation works as well:

```js
var inauguration = new Date("January 20, 2017 12:00:00");
var now = Date.now();
var diff = (inauguration.getTime() - now) / 1000;
var clock = $('#clock').FlipClock(diff, {
  countdown: true,
  clockFace: "DailyCounter"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm...that gives me 18693 days. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I got it after I looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates

Comment: @ParkerThomas Tell me what's the issue, I'll update my answer, so that you can accept it.

Comment: Take a look at my original question, I added the working code.

Comment: Oh okay, they are milliseconds... `:D`

Comment: But, yeah... I gave the idea of using `.getTime()` right? `:)`

Comment: Yep. Divided by 1000 and also remembered that JS counts January as `00`. Oops :D

Comment: Yea, that's true... Months are 0 indexed.

Comment: @ParkerThomas Approved boss.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the working code. Once it is peer reviewed I can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ParkerThomas It's reviewed and approved. You should have got 2 points.

Comment: I agree. Looks like it's gone. Not sure how that happened.

Comment: @ParkerThomas Also, you can keep the original version of `new Date("January 20, 2017 12:00:00");`...

Comment: @ParkerThomas I reopened.

Comment: @ParkerThomas Check my answer now, with the snippet.

Comment: FWIW, it's not necessary to call `.getTime()`. The date object is converted to a number automatically. I.e. `inauguration.getTime() - now` and `inauguration - now` produce the same result. It's still good to be explicit about it, but it's not *necessary*.

Comment: @FelixKling I came to know after some time... `:D`