# CSS fade after an exact date

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

How can I change a text/div/pic after an exact date?

For example here's a code what changes the div like an overlay.
I would like that result when an exact date past.

So for example after 2018.01.01 the div automatically changes to grey. How should I code this? Tips? :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDiv").click(function() {
        $("#overlay").show();
    });
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 50px 50px;
    padding:10px;
}

#overlay {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: gray;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
<p>Some text</p>
<input type="button" value="A button" >
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQRZc/

Comment: simply change it manually after this date ... why an automatic script for one date ?

Comment: It wouldn't be for only a date there'll be a lot of them. I just wanted to know how I can create it. Or the mechanism.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO jquery is javascript but we don't have to add Javascript tag for all jquery questions .... if someone know jQuery so he also know JS but someone can know JS and not jQuery .. so JS tag should be used for issue related to JS or if the OP decide it should be done with JS

Comment: Then start by properly researching this, please. You are not the first person ever to try and change what it is shown on a web site dynamically based on the current time. Please go read [ask]. Or in short: When you are still at the _“How should I code this?”_ or _“I just wanted to know how”_ level with your own research & efforts, it is simply too early to come here.

Comment: `It wouldn't be for only a date there'll be a lot of them` --> so you question is not relevant with your real need

Comment: Further to @CBroe's comment, all your asking is 'How do I compare todays date to another known date'. As such I closed this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You take the current date+time, and subtract that from the target date+time, this will result in an amount of seconds until the target date+time. [This answer gives a good working example for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates), but you could also pre-calculate this serverside, e.g. with PHP.

```
// Then a simple settimeout will do the rest:
setTimeout(
    function(){ $("#overlay").show(); },
    secondsTillTarget*1000
);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks, now I have a line where I can go.