# How to get the number of seconds between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the number of seconds between two dates in javascript.
Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024198/how-many-seconds-between-two-dates) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894632/get-time-difference-between-two-dates-in-seconds) suggest that a simple subtract operation should do the trick and other answers suggest that you use either the `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()` attributes.
But Despite all that when I subtract the two dates, Which are apart by 5 seconds I get the value `1551181475795` which is way too large to be correct.
Here is my code:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:25").valueOf();
var dist = 347155200;
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:30");

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = Math.abs(now - countDownDate / 1000);
  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = distance;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id='demo'>
```

As you can see both times are only apart by 5 seconds but the value that separates them makes no sense.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why are you dividing `countDownDate` by 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of operations order, you're dividing the `countDownDate` by `1000` before doing the subtraction (you're calculating `now - countDownDate / 1000` however, you should calculate `(now - countDownDate) / 1000`, subtraction first):

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:25").valueOf();
var dist = 347155200;
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:30");

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = Math.abs((now - countDownDate) / 1000);
  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = distance;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I feel like I should have caught that!

Answer (score 0):

As you had researched you can simply reduce the newer date from the older one which returns the milliseconds between the two dates.

Dividing that with 1000 gives you the seconds.

```js
let start = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:25")
let end = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:30");
let secondsBetween = (end - start) / 1000;
console.log("without value of:", secondsBetween, "seconds")

start = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:25").valueOf()
end = new Date("Mar 16, 2019 16:33:30").valueOf()
secondsBetween = (end - start) / 1000;

console.log("using value of:",(end - start) / 1000, "seconds")
```